# SOQL query for Multiselect picklist

Tags: soql, query, multi-select

Hello I'm trying to use string in SOQL query where clause for multiselect picklist.

I need to get records of CustObj__c where Multipicklist__c fild have 'abc' or 'xyz' values.

```
String str = '\'abc\',\'xyz\'';
for(CustObj__c cust : [Select Id, Name, Multipicklist__c FROM CustObj__c WHERE Multipicklist INCLUDES (:str)]{
somelogic
}
```

However I get no records. 
What is wrong in this query?

Ok I tried using list too, here I'm getting all record of all Public Groups where user is assign. and saving those Public Groups names in

```
List<String> groupIds = new List<String>();
List<String> groupNames = new List<String>();

for(GroupMember gm :[SELECT Id,GroupId,UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE UserOrGroupId = :userIds[0]]){
            groupIds.add(gm.GroupId);
        }
        for(Group g :[SELECT ID,Name FROM Group WHERE Id IN :groupIds]){
            groupNames.add('\'' + g.Name + '\'');
        }

for(CustObj__c cust : [Select Id, Name, Multipicklist__c FROM CustObj__c WHERE Multipicklist INCLUDES (:groupNames)]){
somelogic
}
```

It still not working

I get error in Dev console : Invalid bind expression type of List for column of type String

Comment: Pretty sure you would need to do `INCLUDES ('abc', 'xyz')`. Or declare a `List<String> selections = new List<String> {  'abc', 'xyz' };` then `INCLUDES :selections`, but I don't have any multi-select picklists to test against.

Comment: Why are you adding `'\'` in the line `groupNames.add('\'' + g.Name + '\'');`? Also, you're doing a query in a loop. Please consider taking that out.

Comment: as my List<String> groupNames = {abc , xyz} and i thought it supposed to be like {'abc' , 'xyz'} so i modified it to groupNames.add('\'' + g.Name + '\''); output for List<String> groupName = {'abc' , 'xyz'}. In any case when i use this List groupNames in where clause it gives "Invalid bind expression type of List for column of type String" error

Comment: [You cannot use bind variables with `INCLUDES`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm)

Comment: The converse is `EXCLUDES ('123')` for the negative case where you want all but a few values.  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_multiselect_picklists.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my answer from this question thanks to @Anmol Kumar.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/301892/60388

**Answer is below :**

You need to create a query string first and then pass it to Database.query

**Example**

```
for(Group g :[SELECT ID,Name FROM Group WHERE Id IN :groupIds]) {
    groupNames.add(g.Name);
}

String value = '(\'' + String.join(groupNames, '\',\'') + '\')';
String queryString = 'SELECT Id, Name, MultiSelectPicklist__c FROM Program__c where MultiSelectPicklist__c INCLUDES ' + value;
List<program__c> newlist = DataBase.query(queryString);
system.debug('List of records: '+newlist);
```

Answer (score 0):

Multi-select picklists requires to have a List to filter your INCLUDES against if you have multiple values to filter out:

```
List<String> strList = new List<String> { 'abc', 'xyz' };
for (CustObj__c cust : [Select Id, Name, Multipicklist__c FROM CustObj__c WHERE Multipicklist INCLUDES :strList) {
    ....
```

Comment: @it's not working. INCLUDE operator is not taking (:<List>string)

Answer (score 0):

This is for you if you have XYZ, ABC, PQR picklist values in your multi-picklist field and wanted to query on it `String sampleString = 'ABC';`

```
Select id, Name, APINameOfMultiPickField FROM ObjectAPIName
WHERE APINameOfMultiPickField includes (:sampleString)
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Your answer needs improvement. *Firstly*, it is not valid Apex. *Secondly*, according to the comment (with a link to Salesforce documentation) from @DavidCheng under the question, you cannot use a bind variable (e.g., `:sampleString`) with `INCLUDES`. If you have information that this has changed, please include documentation. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/360029/edit) your answer to address these items.

Answer (score 0):

The correct, working syntax  is -
Select id, Name, APINameOfMultiPickField FROM ObjectAPIName
WHERE APINameOfMultiPickField includes ('sampleString')

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/190323)