# Multiselect picklist SOQL error

Tags: soql, multi-select

I'm trying to get records of custom object where MultiSelectPicklist__c have names of publicgroups.

```
List<String> groupIds = new List<String>();
List<String> groupNames = new List<String>();

for(GroupMember gm :[SELECT Id,GroupId,UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE UserOrGroupId = '0051U000006AkQy']){
groupIds.add(gm.GroupId);
}

for(Group g :[SELECT ID,Name FROM Group WHERE Id IN :groupIds]){
groupNames.add(g.Name);
}

for(CustObj__c cust : [Select Id, Name, MultiSelectPicklist__c FROM CustObj__c WHERE MultiSelectPicklist__c INCLUDES (:groupNames)] ){
somelogic
}
```

Why it says '**Invalid bind expression type of List<'String> for column of type String**' in developer console?

Even after converting List to string I'm still not able to get any record

```
for(GroupMember gm :[SELECT Id,GroupId,UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE UserOrGroupId = :userIds[0]]){
            groupIds.add(gm.GroupId);
        }
        for(Group g :[SELECT ID,Name FROM Group WHERE Id IN :groupIds]){
            groupNames.add('\'' + g.Name + '\'');
            //groupNames.add(g.Name);
        }

        String listtostring = String.join(groupnames, ',');

        List<program__c> newlist = [SELECT Id, Name, MultiSelectPicklist__c FROM Program__c where MultiSelectPicklist__c INCLUDES (:listtostring) ];
        system.debug('List of records---'+newlist);
```

- I tried both

```
for(Group g :[SELECT ID,Name FROM Group WHERE Id IN :groupIds]){
            ///groupNames.add('\'' + g.Name + '\'');
            groupNames.add(g.Name);
        }
```

Comment: Please [edit your post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/301869/edit) to specify the line that is throwing the error.

Comment: for(CustObj__c cust : [Select Id, Name, MultiSelectPicklist__c FROM CustObj__c WHERE MultiSelectPicklist__c INCLUDES (:groupNames)] ){

This is the line it shows error on my code..

Comment: please do not post duplicate questions.

Comment: No. I tried suggestion provided which is what my code show above. but it throws that error. Why i'm not able to put List<String> after INCLUDES ? I tried converting List<string> to string too, then It don't give error but there is no expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a query string first and then pass it to Database.query

**Example**

```
for(Group g :[SELECT ID,Name FROM Group WHERE Id IN :groupIds]) {
    groupNames.add(g.Name);
}

String value = '(\'' + String.join(groupNames, '\',\'') + '\')';
String queryString = 'SELECT Id, Name, MultiSelectPicklist__c FROM Program__c where MultiSelectPicklist__c INCLUDES ' + value;
List<program__c> newlist = DataBase.query(queryString);
system.debug('List of records: '+newlist);
```